# Explanation query with GROUP_BY and ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to understand how queries works with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY enabled.

If i list all the columns of the table with a MIN() on one column, it works fine:

```
$query = "SELECT id, member_id, name, code, MIN(price) AS price, FROM tbl_product GROUP BY code";
```

But if I select everything I have an error:

```
$query = "SELECT *, MIN(price) AS price FROM tbl_product GROUP BY code";
```

Can you explain me the differences between both ?

Comment: What's the database? Is it MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's about a bug that was fixed in MySQL 5.7.5. According to the manual [12.20.3 MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) MySQL 5.7.5 and newer can detect functional dependence between the primary key and the rest of the columns of the table. Literally it says:

> MySQL 5.7.5 and up implements detection of functional dependence. If the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode is enabled (which it is by default), MySQL rejects queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are neither named in the GROUP BY clause nor are functionally dependent on them.

`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is now the default option and works as specified by the SQL Standard.

Answer (score 1):

The question is really why you would think that `group by` would work with `select *`.

What `group by` does is produce one row for each combination of values for the `group by` keys.  That is by definition.  Multiple rows become one.

The expressions allowed in the `select` are then:

- The group by keys or expressions containing only those keys.
- Summary functions on other values.
- Combinations of summary functions with group by keys.

Any column in the `select` that is not in the `group by` could have *multiple* values among the original row.  SQL does not allow this.  Most databases do not allow this.  MySQL no longer allows this by default.

Once upon a time it did, but the returned values were from indeterminate matching rows.  That "functionality" (really a bug) has now been fixed.

Note:  There is an exception to this -- allowed by the standard -- that allows aggregating by primary keys/unique keys and then select the rest of the columns.  This is allowed because the primary key uniquely identifies the rest of the column values.